# Links in second language not working when logged out

Tags: users, i18n-l10n

I have inherited a Drupal web site with a lot of modules installed. Part of these modules have been setup to allow for translation of web site elements between English and French.

The site is configured to use paths prefix (mywebsite.com/fr) to indicate items from another language.

When I am logged in as administrator, I can access mywebsite.com/fr and see the french version of the homepage. When I am logged out, trying to get to the same address just redirects me to the english root (mywebsite.com).

Any ideas on where there may be a setting that would only allow logged in users to see translated content?

Answer (score 1):

After much searching, I have code in the site's theme folder, within template.php, that made a call to the drupal_goto function if the connected user was not logged in, for all page requests where the language is set to french.

A search for $base_url led me to find this. Although now seeing that the redirection function in drupal is drupal_goto, I could have found this a lot quicker with a search for that call.